# Devils ivy plant leaves are growing with a cut in them; what can I do to prevent it?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, indoors

[image]

How can I fix my devils ivy plant? It's growing fine but the new leaves are getting cracked or have a cut in them. I'm looking for suggestions.

Comment: this looks like mechanical damage from the leaves getting bent when moved. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I don't think its d reason as have not moved it around since day one .... Not sure what's happening!!!